# Can not access IHttpRequest within ServiceStack Mvc Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, servicestack

Sorry for my lack of understanding regarding the web stack but this has been haunting me for a couple days.

I am trying figure out how to access Request as a IHttpRequest within  the web controllers of the  https://github.com/ServiceStack/SocialBootstrapApi example.

It is currently a MVC3 app with ServiceStack's MVC PowerPack. My request always resolves to a System.Web.HttpRequest. I created an extension method on IHttpRequest to check if the current request is coming from a mobile device but it never gets picked up because all my requests are System.Web.HttpRequests instead of a ServiceStack.ServiceHost.IHttpRequest. any help would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like

```
var httpReq = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.ToRequestContext().Get<IHttpRequest>();
```

to turn the request from System.Web.HttpRequest into a ServiceStack.ServiceHost.IHttpRequest.

The requests going into the Controllers of the SocialBootstrapApi examples don't come through the 'ServiceStack pipeline'. The Controllers do [inherit from ServiceStackConroller](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions#typed-sessions-in-mvc) but I think its purpose is to share Session data between MVC and ServiceStack. The ServiceStackContoller doesn't take over the request/response like a request going into the `/api path` which is handled entirely by ServiceStack in the example project.

Comment: thanks! this worked well. is the socialbootstrap example out dated by chance? or is there a better way to do this other than using microsoft's mvc ?